# Understanding Springboot MySql Authentication Config

Tags: mysql, authentication, spring-boot

I am messing around with Spring authentication in a Springboot project using MySql to store users and user_roles. I have my database wired up with no issues but am having a hard time understanding exactly how the "magic" spring authentication is supposed to work behind the scenes. Below is what I have so far...

**...Web config...**

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

 @Autowired
 private DataSource dataSource;

 @Autowired
 public void configureAuth(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
    .usersByUsernameQuery("select * from mydatabase.users where username=?")
    .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select * from mydatabase.user_roles where username=?");

 }

 @Override
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/cardPage").permitAll()
    .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login");

 }
}
```

**...HTML FORM...**

```
<form class="col s12" action="/login" method="post">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input id="username" name="username" type="text" class="validate" /> <label for="username">Username</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input id="password" name="password" type="password" class="validate" /> <label for="password">Password</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row center">
        <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">
            Submit <i class="mdi-content-send right"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}" th:value="${_csrf.token}" />
</form>
```

I am able to login to my form and submit the username and password and I can definetly see spring firing the first query defined in the "configureAuth" method in my security configurations, but it seems to just fail after that and returns a param.error to my login.jsp. Below is the console output. As can be seen, the jdbcAuthentication appears to be partially working as it does fire off the first query, but it never appears to fire the second in the .authoritiesByUserNameQuery. I am using thymeleaf as a template engine and can definitely see there are errors in **param.error** on the client side of things but I'm not sure how to get more information out of either the param.error in the html page or at least enable more useful logging in the server side of things. Is there some kind of logging configuration I can use to expose springs behind the scenes stuff to at least have a clue where things are going wrong? Do I need to have my database setup in a specific way for this security model? If needed I can paste pics of what my tables look like.

```
2017-03-02 20:01:28.522 DEBUG 12460 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL query
2017-03-02 20:01:28.522 DEBUG 12460 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [select * from mydatabase.users where username=?]
2017-03-02 20:01:28.528 DEBUG 12460 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils      : Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
2017-03-02 20:01:33.898 TRACE 12460 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] o.s.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils      : Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 1, parameter value [user], value class [java.lang.String], SQL type unknown
2017-03-02 20:01:34.049 DEBUG 12460 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils      : Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
2017-03-02 20:01:34.056 DEBUG 12460 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] o.s.b.w.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter    : Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@467d2a7f
2017-03-02 20:01:34.066 DEBUG 12460 --- [nio-8081-exec-5] o.s.b.w.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter    : Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@467d2a7f
2017-03-02 20:01:34.086 DEBUG 12460 --- [nio-8081-exec-5] o.s.b.w.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter    : Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@467d2a7f
```

Comment: Update: I added logging.level.org.springframework.security = DEBUG and it greatly increased the console output. Still working on it... Will add more if I am able to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding the DEBUG logging for the org.springframework.security = DEBUG I found that my database was the culprit. I didn't have a column in my "users" table for "enabled". Apparently the spring framework needs this value (TINYINT in this case as 1 = enabled, 0 = disabled). After updating my database with this field I am able to successfully login via authentication, there's also some very straightforward logging that spring spits out to help understand how things work behind the scenes, I highly recommend adding this logging level if your starting with Spring security.